# why can't change data with data.entry in while loop?

Tags: r

```
change<-function(){
play <- scan(what="character")
numbers<-c("1","3","4","9","10")
while(! all(is.element(play,numbers))){
   data.entry(play)
}}
change()
```

When i input 3 4 100 with scan ,and change it in data.entry,but the changed data will not be assigned into play ,why?

as  @r2evans said ,i fix my code into the following,problem solved.

```
change<-function(){
play <- scan(what="character")
numbers<-c("1","3","4","9","10")
while(! all(is.element(play,numbers))){
   data.entry(play)
   return(play)
}}
change()
```

It isn't  still a good technic,when i put the code in a program ,the code after return(play) will never be executed.

I fix it as:

```
change<-function(){
play <- scan(what="character")
numbers<-c("1","3","4","9","10")
while(! all(is.element(play,numbers))){
   play <- fix(play)
}}
change()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `data.entry`, but it appears to work fine for me.

Comment: If you provide `data.entry` we might be able to provide some insight. Lacking that, functions in general shouldn't be relying on "side effects," so `play` is being passed by value and not by reference. This means any changes to it inside the function are local to the function and are lost if not returned *and captured*.